# How to find all participants of a chat thread?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

In my database I have the following tables: `user, post, post_participant, and post_reply`, largely as inspiration from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542556/962155).

One thing I'm having trouble with figuring out though is how to find all the participants of a post.

For example, one way would be to just do a `SELECT DISTINCT user` on the `post_reply` table for a given `post_id`, but this would be missing the original poster if they hadn't replied to their own thread.

Okay, easy enough: do a `SELECT` on the `post` table as well and then do `UNION ALL` with the `SELECT` on the `post_reply` table. The problem with that though is that for my application I need to order this result set by post date, so the author should always be on top, and `UNION ALL` messes up the order.

Okay, fair enough, I can then just use multiple CTEs (union the first, distinct the second, and then finally order by). Except at this point it's become quite complex just to find out all the participants for a post.

The `SELECT DISTINCT` may also get slow once a post has many replies as well, since I'd imagine it's O(n).

An alternative is that the original poster and all posters can be added to the `post_participant` table.

The problem with *that* though, is that I'm not really sure if it's possible to do this efficiently. Do I just need to do `INSERT INTO post_participant ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` literally every time anyone makes a reply to a post? That seems extremely inefficient. Or is there a way to cheaply determine whether or not it's someone's first reply to a post, to avoid this database call?

It seems like there are no good solutions to this. Either I have to do an additional write attempt on every reply call, or I have to do a slow and complex `DISTINCT UNION` every time a post is opened. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use post_participant table? It's best to post your schema to review, sorry I am lazy to read the ref link in your question.

Comment: I mention in the OP that I'm confused about how to efficiently use the `post_participant` table. It seems like you have to do an additional write on literally every single post reply. Is there not a better way?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with that though is that for my application I need to order this result set by post date, so the author should always be on top, and `UNION ALL` messes up the order.

Actually, the order should be preserved as `UNION ALL` is implemented to just append rows. (Might be revealing to include the offending query in your question.)
Also, you might merge tables `post` and `post_reply`into a single table. Depends.

And if you typically have many rows per user in a chat, use a ***recursive CTE*** to get the distinct count of users with best performance using a matching index:

- [Fast way to count distinct column values (using an index?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57560949/939860)